# Why regex object doesn't work when it be assigned outside of the "for" loop?JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

it doesn't work when it was:

```
function test(str) {
   var vowelsCount = 0;
   var arr = str.split('');
   var regex = new RegExp(/[aeiou]/, 'gi');
   arr.forEach((item, index, array) =>{
      if(regex.test(item)){
         vowelsCount++;
      }
   });
   return vowelsCount;
}
test('pear tree');   //2,it passes a and the second e
```

it works when it was:

```
arr.forEach((item, index, array) =>{
   var regex = new RegExp(/[aeiou]/, 'gi');
   if(regex.test(item)){
      vowelsCount++;
   }
});
```

why the regex object doesn't correct when it was assigned outside of the loop?

Comment: As an aside: you can shorten your code to [`return str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;`](https://jsfiddle.net/2z6wfm63/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `g` flag. Remove the global flag and it will work. The reason is that when you use `g` flag in the `regex` variable you have `lastIndex` field. When you use the `regex` on different array strings, this index holds incorrect value. In the second example works because you define new `regex` in each iteration and `lastIndex` field is set to 0 each time. You can also reset that index manually.

```
function test(str) {
   var vowelsCount = 0;
   var arr = str.split('');
   var regex = new RegExp(/[aeiou]/, 'gi');
   arr.forEach((item, index, array) =>{
      if(regex.test(item)){
         vowelsCount++;
      }
      regex.lastIndex = 0
   });
   return vowelsCount;
}
test('pear tree');
```